# Mysql: How do I access the value of a column for my current row

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a mysql table that has columns
Part # (varchar) and customer # (varchar)

I am trying to create a third column that counts unique pairings of Part #'s with a list of customer #'s.

```
select Part_num, Cust_num, 
  (select count(*) from my_table where Part_num = (The current value of Part_num) 
    and Cust_num in (select Cust_num from my_table where Part_num = 'XYZ123')) as Pairs
from my_table;
```

I am trying to figure out how many Customer #'s contain the current part.  If I substitute (The current value of Part_num) for a Part # say "ABC789" then the query correctly identifies their being X number of pairs, but I need to do this dynamically for every Part #.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck solving this?

Comment: I am going to go about it with a stored procedure.

Comment: Okay. I can edit my answer if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks man.  I'm going to work on it for a few hours and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do here is select the part number, use the COUNT() aggregate function, and group by customer number that way you will get the count of each customer associated with that part.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT partNumber, COUNT(*) AS numCustomers
FROM myTable
WHERE partNumber = 'ABC789';
```

If it's possible for a customer number to appear more than once, and you want distinct customers, you can put `distinct customerNumber` in your COUNT clause:

```
SELECT partNumber, COUNT(distinct customerNumber) AS numCustomers
FROM myTable
WHERE partNumber = 'ABC789';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the outer query from the [(correlated) subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), you just need to use table aliases.

```
SELECT t.part_num, 
       t.cust_num, 
       ( 
              SELECT Count(*) 
              FROM   my_table t2
              WHERE  t2.part_num = t.part_num
              AND    cust_num IN 
                     ( 
                            SELECT cust_num 
                            FROM   my_table 
                            WHERE  part_num = 'XYZ123')) AS pairs 
FROM   my_table t;
```